# jhipster application failled run : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-3, jhipster

i created a jhipster application and run it over inteljidea,
i got this error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/Users/retina/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.0.3/springfox-swagger2-2.0.3.jar!/springfox/documentation/swagger2/mappers/LicenseMapper$License.class]; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/mapstruct/Qualifier : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:303) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:140) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:266) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:486) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:276) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:103) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78) [junit-rt.jar:na]
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212) [junit-rt.jar:na]
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68) [junit-rt.jar:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140) [idea_rt.jar:na]
>   C

Comment: Are you trying to run with Java 7? What happens if you run with Java 8?

Comment: i fixed the problem by running over intelljidea and it worked, on netbeans still have the problem !! on intelljidea works with java 8, i'll try the java 7 on netbeans and tell you

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1722

try to delete:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

in yours pom.xml